# How to manage a list in python

Tags: python, list

Here are the two lists I have  :

```
l1 = ['5', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45']
l2 = ['0.011530', '0.039914', '0.085069', '0.145798', '0.213572', '0.287898', '0.355587', '0.413209', '0.472346']
```

thanks to these two lists I would like to create two lists with the same values but with some changes :

```
new_list1 = [5,10,10,15,15,20,20,25,25,30,30,35,35,40,40,45,45]
new_list2 = ['0.011530', '0.011530', '0.039914', '0.039914', '0.085069', '0.085069', '0.145798', '0.145798', '0.213572', '0.213572', '0.287898', '0.287898', '0.355587', '0.355587', '0.413209', '0.413209', '0.472346']
```

the purpose of this two new lists is to create a graph and instead of a line, I will get steps.
[What I dont want]
[image: 1]

[What I want]
[image: 2]

so as a beginner i wrote that :

```
def test():
 
  new_list1.insert(0,l1[0])
  new_list2.insert(0,l2[0])

  new_list1.insert(1,l1[1])
  new_list2.insert(1,l2[0])

  new_list1.insert(2,l1[1])
  new_list2.insert(2,l2[1])

  new_list1.insert(3,l1[2])
  new_list2.insert(3,l2[1])

  new_list1.insert(4,l1[2])
  new_list2.insert(4,l2[2])
  
  new_list1.insert(5,l1[3])
  new_list2.insert(5,l2[2])

  new_list1.insert(6,l1[3])
  new_list2.insert(6,l2[3])

  new_list1.insert(7,l1[4])
  new_list2.insert(7,l2[3])
  
  new_list1.insert(8,l1[4])
  new_list2.insert(8,l2[4])

  new_list1.insert(9,l1[5])
  new_list2.insert(9,l2[4])

  new_list1.insert(10,l1[5])
  new_list2.insert(10,l2[5])
  
  new_list1.insert(11,l1[6])
  new_list2.insert(11,l2[5])

  new_list1.insert(12,l1[6])
  new_list2.insert(12,l2[6])

  new_list1.insert(13,l1[7])
  new_list2.insert(13,l2[6])
  
  new_list1.insert(14,l1[7])
  new_list2.insert(14,l2[7])

  new_list1.insert(15,l1[8])
  new_list2.insert(15,l2[7])

  new_list1.insert(16,l1[8])
  new_list2.insert(16,l2[8])

  print(new_list1)
  print(new_list2)

  x = np.array(new_list1) 
  y = np.array(new_list2)
  
  # plotting
  plt.title("Line graph") 
  plt.xlabel("X axis") 
  plt.ylabel("Y axis") 
  plt.plot(x, y, color ="green") 
  plt.show()
```

which makes the trick, but I want it to be more "beautiful" and easy to read, with some "for" loop.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Is `l1` meant to have 2 `5` or is it just one `5`?

Comment: First of all. Why are you using `insert`? Can't you just use `append` instead?

Comment: @ThePilotDude yeah only  1 -> `5`

Comment: `plot()` takes an argument `drawstyle='steps'`

Comment: @thethiny  because i dont know how to use append, and i think the function is more intuitive. but if it's better to use append I'll try to change

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Oof, ok thank you, it seems easier to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mess with your original array at all!
`plt.plot()` takes an argument `drawstyle`, which you can set to `'steps'` to get your desired output without any changes to the original array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l1 = ['5', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45']
l2 = ['0.011530', '0.039914', '0.085069', '0.145798', '0.213572', '0.287898', '0.355587', '0.413209', '0.472346']

x = [int(v) for v in l1]
y = [float(k) for k in l2]

plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps')
```

[image]

However, note that this is **not** the plot you want: In your plot, the first horizontal line is at the `y=0.011530`, but in this one it is at `y=0.039914`.

To fix this, you simply need to duplicate the last `x` value and the first `y` value

```
x.insert(-1, x[-1])
y.insert(0, y[0])
plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps')
```

[image]

---

If you still want to mess with your array, use a loop!

```
new_list_x = []
new_list_y = []
# zip three lists: 
#    0th through penultimate elements of x -> currentX
#    0th through penultimate elements of y -> currentY
#    1st through last elements of x -> nextX
for currentX, currentY, nextX in zip(x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:]):
    # Add the point at the current (x, y)
    new_list_x.append(currentX)
    new_list_y.append(currentY)

    # Add the point at the next x but the current y
    new_list_x.append(nextX)
    new_list_y.append(currentY)

plt.plot(new_list_x, new_list_y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you i will change it now !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.step(x,t)` this way:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l1 = ['5', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45']
l2 = ['0.011530', '0.039914', '0.085069', '0.145798', '0.213572', '0.287898', '0.355587', '0.413209', '0.472346']

x = [int(v) for v in l1]
y = [float(k) for k in l2]

plt.step(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I really went too far

Comment: is it normal to get this error ?  `x = [int(v) for v in l1]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' `

Comment: @Kiri the list you are using is the same with this example? Are all values integer?

Comment: oops i didnt see, Imade a mistake thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the `for` loop that I believe replaces your `insert` functions.

```
def test():
  for i in range(16+1):
    new_list1.append(l1[i//2+i%2])
    new_list2.append(l2[i//2])
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `range(16+1)`

Comment: @ThePilotDude I can write 17, but since in his question he needed 16 I just gave 16 as an example. I didn't use `len(list)` since I'm unsure what he needed precisely, and he asked for a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is my method, which I think is pretty easy to understand:

```py
new_lst1 = []
new_lst2 = []

for count, i in enumerate(l1):
    if count != 0:
        new_lst1.append(int(i))
        new_lst1.append(int(i))
    else:
        new_lst1.append(int(i))

for count, i in enumerate(l2):
    if count != len(l2) - 1:
        new_lst2.append(i)
        new_lst2.append(i)
    else:
        new_lst2.append(i)
```

Basically, the `enumerate` allows us to loop through the list while simultaneously getting the count of the list. This allows us to only add one `5`.

Comment: Did you forget to `count%2`?

Comment: No I just thought it would make it harder to read. I prefer to use a simple method for simple cases like this.